# Last data traffic time for a TCP socket

Tags: linux, networking, socket, timeout

Is it possible, to find out when was the last time there was any traffic on an opened TCP socket?

Keepalive and timeout timers are based on this statistic, so I guess it has to be stored somewhere.

OS is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: *Keepalive and timeout timers are based on this statistic, so I guess it has to be stored somewhere.* True, almost certainly RAM allocated to the process owning the socket.  If it's stored somewhere else as well, then it may be queryable externally, but if it's just that, you are out of luck with the direct route.  I don't know either way.

Comment: You can access the timer data via `netstat -o` or `ss -o` but I don't think they provide you with what you want/need, at least not based on my tests.

Comment: @UlrichDangel thanks, I know about these timers. They are why I suspect there must be a value they are checking :-)